# Need help to convert a pattern in a .txt file to something else

Tags: notepad++, text-editors

So guys,

```
3076482 FinalDesir  jotdhaliwal@shaw.ca 174.5.141.202   aedcbbf6570e664723318f5e57658625:KHG5CzJ3EO/mVta?<ZR*4b%9ucb?sa
```

For example I have this line ^

I want to convert it into

```
jotdhaliwal@shaw.ca:aedcbbf6570e664723318f5e57658625:KHG5CzJ3EO/mVta?<ZR*4b%9ucb?sa
```

Answer (score 1):

- Find what: `^(?:\S+\h+){2}(\S+)\h+\S+\h+`
- Replace with: `$1:`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               # beginning of line
  (?:           # start non capture group
    \S+         # 1 or more non space characters
    \h+         # 1 or more horizontal spaces
  ){2}          # end group, must appear twice
  (\S+)         # group 1, 1 or more non space characters
  \h+           # 1 or more horizontal spaces
  \S+           # 1 or more non space characters
  \h+           # 1 or more horizontal spaces
```

**Result for given example:**

```
jotdhaliwal@shaw.ca:aedcbbf6570e664723318f5e57658625:KHG5CzJ3EO/mVta?<ZR*4b%9ucb?sa
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]